# Print user inputted number with commas and the numbers in between

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to code a simple script.

What I want the script to do is ask the user for the first number, then asks for the second number, then prints out both of these numbers including the numbers in between and add commas.

For example:
Lets say the user inputted the number 2 as the first number
then inputs 10 as the second number
the script will print out this: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

This is my code:

```
number_1 = int(raw_input("Input first number:"));
number_2 = int(raw_input("Input second number:"));
print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number_1 = int(raw_input("Input first number:"))
number_2 = int(raw_input("Input second number:"))
```

You can use `join` with a generator to create a list of numbers

```
numbers = ','.join(str(i) for i in range(number_1, number_2 + 1))
print(numbers)
```

To understand what the above line is doing, here is a more step-by-step equivalent(ish).

```
numberList = []
for num in range(number_1, number_2 + 1):
    numberList.append(str(num))
numbers = ','.join(numberList)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: He also wants the numbers between number 1 and number 2 to be printed.

Comment: Thank you! just what I needed. Is there a more simpler way to do this? your code was very helpful :)

Comment: @Louis I added a simpler method lower in the post. Both methods do the same idea, one just uses a bit more advanced technique to do so.